# Grammar Rules for syntax on declaring a variable in Perl?

Tags: perl, syntax, grammar, rules

I am looking for a few a examples of the grammar rules that structure syntax when declaring a variable in Perl. I have no personal experience with Perl and wondered if someone here could assist?

Comment: Read a book or online tutorial for absolute Perl beginners. We can't teach you the most fundamental language constructs here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

read `perldoc perlvar`

If it isn't on your system, google it

Comment: IMO the best web rendition is [perldoc.perl.org](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html)